# REXML::ParseException in BoxfileController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services

I have been trying to create dropbox like aws base cloud hosting app in rails. I have already add most of feature in app. But recently i am facing issuse with following error.

```
REXML::ParseException in BoxfileController#index
Missing end tag for 'meta' (got "head") Line: 6 Position: 354 Last 80 unconsumed characters:
 end
        @userfiles = AWS::S3::Bucket.objects(BUCKET_NAME, :prefix => current_user.folder)
    end
```

These are my following file in app.

airbox/boxfile_controller.rb

```
class BoxfileController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def index
        if current_user.folder.nil?
            current_user.folder = generate_random_user_folder_name
            current_user.save
        end
        @userfiles = AWS::S3::Bucket.objects(BUCKET_NAME, :prefix => current_user.folder)
    end
    end

    def add
    end

    def upload
        begin
          AWS::S3::S3Object.store(sanitize_filename(params[:boxfile].original_filename), 
                                    params[:boxfile].read, BUCKET_NAME, :access => :public_read)
          redirect_to boxfile_path, :notice => "Your file was successfully uploaded to ShareBox"
        rescue
          redirect_to boxfile_path, :error => "Your file couldn't be uploaded to ShareBox"
        end
    end

    def delete
        if (params[:file_id])  
            AWS::S3::S3Object.find(params[:file_id], BUCKET_NAME).delete  
            redirect_to boxfile_path, :notice => params[:file_id].sub(current_user.folder + '/','') + " was deleted"
        else  
            redirect_to boxfile_path, :error => "Could not delete " + params[:file_id].sub(current_user.folder + '/','') 
        end  
    end

    def sanitize_filename(file_name)
        just_filename = File.basename(file_name)
        File.join(current_user.folder, just_filename.sub(/[^\w\.\-]/,'_'))
    end

    def generate_random_user_folder_name()
        letters = [('a'..'z'), ('A'..'Z')].map { |i| i.to_a }.flatten
        return (0...8).map{ letters[rand(letters.length)] }.join
    end

end
```

airbox/application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module Sharebox
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms = true
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
    AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(  
        :access_key_id     => 'AKIAJB3GGLYUKI64NJKQ',  
        :secret_access_key => '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'
    )  
    end
end
```

and environment.rb file

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
Sharebox::Application.initialize!

BUCKET_NAME = "airboxinrails"

AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
      :access_key_id     => ACCESS_KEY,
      :secret_access_key => SECREY_KEY
    )
```

and for more details i have uploaded to github 
https://github.com/aruzmeister/AirBox

Can anybody help me with the bug..?

Comment: The problem clearly is in this piece of code: `AWS::S3::Bucket.objects(BUCKET_NAME, :prefix => current_user.folder)`

I suggest you look at the source for `aws/s3` gem.  I think it uses Net/HTTP for making HTTP calls.  You can turn the debug mode on to see what Amazon's API returns.

Comment: I seems that the gem expect the "<meta>" tag to have a "</meta>" end tag but maybe the parsed html uses "<meta ..... />" format, check the docs for AWS to see if it says something about that